# Silverlight CallMethodAction

Tags: silverlight

How to get this CallMethodAction method InitBlah?  Currently it doesn't fire.  Am suspecting it the signature that is wrong:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="btnEnter" Content="Enter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="96,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" SourceName="btnEnter">
                <interactions:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="TextBoxTest" />
                <interactions:CallMethodAction MethodName="InitBlah" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
            </interactivity:EventTrigger>

            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" SourceName="btnEnter">
                <interactions:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="TextBoxTest" />
            </interactivity:EventTrigger>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="TextBoxTest" Width="100" Height="100" Visibility="Collapsed">Hello</TextBlock>
```

code behind:

```
 public void InitBlah(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var x = 1;
        }
```

The ChangePropertyAction works fine:  when I hover over the button, the textbox pops up saying hello.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of your `InitBlah` method should be matched for appropriate evets. 
Try this:

```
public void InitBlah(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var x = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.. Actually this didn't work for me, but strangely pointed my in the right direction of using ToolTips instead of manually wiring up mouseevents:  http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-ToolTip-control-in-Silverlight-2.aspx